# Perl fails to open excel file when executing from Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: perl, excel, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

This is a very bizarre problem. I have a Perl (version 5.12) script that opens and modifies an Excel spreadsheet (version 2007 or later). Below is the Perl code to open Excel file:

```
my $excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
            || Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit');
my $book = $excel->Workbooks->Open($excelPath) or die $!;
```

The entire Perl script is added into the Task Scheduler in Windows Server 2008 R2 because it will be called at the same time every day. When I run the script from Task Scheduler, an error occurs at the "Open" statement above and aborts, but $! is completely blank.

However, when I run the Perl script manually from command line, everything works fine including the open-Excel logic. I can't figure out the difference between a command-line execution and a scheduler execution, and why no error message is available when the Open fails.

Please let me know if you have any clue about this issue. Thanks.

**Update**: Thanks to Jason Gray, I'm able to see the error message, which complains that the Excel file cannot be accessed. But this doesn't make sense to me because I can guarantee that file path is correct and that no one else is using the same file. Most importantly, the Perl script works perfectly when running from command window. What might be difference between running from Task Scheduler and running from command line?

**Solved!** I found an odd solution to this odd problem. Please refer to these links:
[Link1](http://www.accessforums.net/programming/macro-having-issues-when-run-windows-scheduler-16921.html) [Link2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/innovateonoffice/thread/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91) [Link3](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/4d6c383a-94eb-4898-9d22-aa4bb69be25b)

Answer (score 1):

The Win32::OLE documentation explains when exceptions will be thrown/how to catch them.

`LastError` gives you information about an error after it has occurred.

You could do something like this:

```
my $book = $excel->Workbooks->Open($excelPath) || 
           die("Unable to open document ", Win32::OLE->LastError());
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to see the error message now, but I still have no clue of a complete solution.

Comment: This may help your situation. Check this out. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559050/processes-spawned-from-a-perl-script-run-via-windows-task-scheduler-dont-have-a)

Answer (score 1):

Please show your `$excelPath` variable. Are you using *absolute* or *relative* paths?

What account do you use to run script from Scheduler? Does it have **enough rights** to access your `$excelPath`?

If your Excel file is located in the same folder as the script itself I recommend to `use FindBin`:

```
use FindBin qw($Bin);

.....

my $book = $excel->Workbooks->Open("$Bin/Document_name.xls") || 
           die("Unable to open document ", Win32::OLE->LastError());
```

Comment: I'm using full path in $excelPath. And the error message I got is:

OLE exception from "Microsoft Office Excel":
Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Book1.xlsx'. There
are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open
workbook.

Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x800a03ec
    in METHOD/PROPERTYGET "Open"

Comment: Are you running Excel in hidden or visible mode? This may mean that you have already running Excel process which block this file. Run Task Manager and kill all running Excel processes. Next try again.

Comment: I have solved the problem although I don't understand why it works. Seems it's a loophole with Excel Interop COM. Please see my update above.